# No debug adapter, can not send 'variables VSCODE

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In  debug console writes this :

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55624/c4f74411-66ec-44b2-9cf6-15efb60f8611
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
**No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'**

i will be grateful if you help me :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817528/vscode-no-debug-adapter-can-not-send-variables

Answer (score 5):

This happens because your program ends very quickly and the VS Code console tries to display an object from your program (you have probably tried to console.log it, right?)

Objects are not transferred from your program to the debugger, and VS Code have to query them when you're expanding it in the console.

Unfortunately, current latest VS Code version is not able to prevent node process to exit. So you have couple of options:

- ignore the error, it should affect only debugger console
- add a breakpoint in the end of your program, so that flush of console happens before node process exit
- use another debugger, e.g. Chrome's inspector
- use raw values in console output, e.g. do `console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }))` instead of `console.log({ x: 5, y: 6 })`
- [create an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) in VS Code repo and wait for it to be fixed
- fix the issue by yourself, look for node's `RuntimeAgent::notify_when_waiting_for_disconnect_` event, which should be used