# No Debugger Available, can not send 'variables'

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have looked into a problem that I got recently when trying out node for the first time, when I put it in and pulled up the Debug Console when I tried to drop down a really long variable it said `No Debugger Available, can not send 'variables' so I tried looking it up and I got to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817528/vscode-no-debug-adapter-can-not-send-variables), after trying all three options

`"console": "integratedTerminal"`
`"console": "externalTerminal"` and `"console": "internalConsole"` none of them seem to have fixed my problem

So what could I have done wrong

Javascript

```
const genData = require('./data.json');
console.log(genData.GenStructure);
```

data.json

```
{
    "GenStructure": [
        "<a> @scenario@ is going to @event@ because @reason@ is inevitable",
        "The best way to get to @place@ is to take a @transport@ from the @place@",
        "@character@'s favorite book @BookTitle@ is in the genre : @BookGenre@"
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\sentenceGen.js",
            "console": "integratedTerminal" //This was changed
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script outside the vs code? I mean just open command line, write `node sentenceGen.js` and hit enter. Does it run?? The `No Debugger Available, can not send 'variables'` might be caused by an error in your app after it exited, so VS Code has no longer access to your app. See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120471

Comment: Ah well, I just tried it again in the external terminal and it worked so probably, would there be a fix to this issue, so then I can see it in vscode?