# VS code debug - is replacing object values with ellipses. How to show object values in debug?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

How can I get the debug console to display the actual values of the sorted object?

The result in the VS Code debug console display as below and are non expandable:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

Here is a simple program outputting a sorted object that I have written in VS Code.

```
const items = [
    { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
    { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
    { name: 'And', value: 45 },
    { name: 'The', value: -12 },
    { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
    { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
  ];

// sort by value
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  });

// console.log(items);
```

Here is the launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` or `utils.inspect` if it's NodeJS (the latter provides options for inspection depth).

Comment: They both work well (utils.inspect looks a lot neater!) thanks.

Comment: Yup, I stumbled across it accidentally only recently and it's been super-helpful working w/ deeply-nested JSON :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCODE: No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817528/vscode-no-debug-adapter-can-not-send-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important: This solution only works if you are using Node.js.**

If you are using Node.js, you can use the built-in `util.inspect()` function.

First, you have to import it using `require()`.

```js
const util = require("util");
```

Then, you can call the `inspect` function. You need to pass in your object as a parameter.

```js
const inspected = util.inspect(obj);
console.log(inspected);
```

Then, you can easily see the object without it being condensed! For more information, see the [`util.inspect()` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options).

---

If you are not using Node.js, you can use `JSON.stringify()`. You can simply use it as so, passing the object as a parameter.

```js
const obj = [
  { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
  { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
  { name: "And", value: 45 },
  { name: "The", value: -12 },
  { name: "Magnetic", value: 13 },
  { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

This should allow you to inspect it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Stringify worked but the output for mine is ugly AF! vscode really sucks in this regard!
[image]

[image]