# No debugger available, can not send 'variables' Node.js error when using vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, vscode-debugger, node-sqlite3

I am currently using a node.js for the first time trying to use it to SELECT in an sqlite3 database code it connects to the database and even makes an array with 9 results which is the number of entries in my database.

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./dummyuserdata.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected successfully.');
});

db.all("SELECT * FROM USERDATA",[],(err,rows) => {
    console.log(rows)
})
```

It should select all entries in the database and print them to console.

Comment: This is specifically a vscode error and should probably have a related tag (maybe `vscode-debugger`?).  Maybe also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61817528/vscode-no-debug-adapter-can-not-send-variables

Comment: Have you tried to move the "db.all" query into the callback function after printing "Connected ...."? How many entries should be returned? And what has this todo with "vscode-debugger" and your title?!  Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Marc, yes i have it doesn't seem to fix the error, there should be 9 entries returned but instead it returns 9 empty arrays.  And will do thank you Marc